# possessive: on (his) holidays?

Tags: possessive-adjectives

I wrote the following sentence, but an Australian added "his" to it. Is it necessary? Why is it added?
Does it make more sense to include "his"?

> Joseph goes hiking on (his?) holidays to break the monotony of daily life.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: I would also write ‘monotony of his daily life’.

Comment: The Australian is right except the sentence does not make sense. I would hope that Joseph goes on holiday to break the monotony of daily life.

Answer (score 1):

"his holidays" sounds like they are his days off, whereas "the holidays" or "holidays" might mean more something of a community-level holiday: for example, Christmas, New Year, national holidays, etc. Depending on your intent, you can say either. In American English, though, most people do not say "his holidays" - rather, they would just say "days off" or "weekends" depending on their intent.

I believe in Australia, "holidays" are used to refer to days where you do not have to go to work, so "his holidays" mean that, while "holidays" would be more general and apply to everyone other than him, and mean days like Christmas and New Year.

Comment: Are you American?

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is use in order to explain that he goes hiking specialy during *his holidays*. (So, he may have put days off for that):

> Joseph goes hiking on (his?) holidays to break the monotony of daily
>   life.

While the one below mean he is going to hike during *public holidays* (for instance Chrismas):

> Joseph goes hiking on holidays to break the monotony of daily
>   life.

This form can also express the idea of **repetition**.

Answer (score -2):

If you wish to specifically talk about what Joseph does during HIS holidays and not holidays in general, then the addition of the possessive pronoun is necessary in order for your sentence to sound more natural.

However, you can also use the definite article ‘the’ in place of ‘his’ to mean holidays in general. As in - “Joseph goes hiking on the holidays to break the monotony of his daily life’’. Both sentences are grammatically correct with slightly different  meanings.

Comment: What if holidays in general are meant?

Comment: Why is 'holidays' any different from 'weekends'?

Comment: How do you know that it's not meant to be holidays in general? The only thing that adding *his* does is subtly alter the meaning of the sentence. Which if fine, if it's intended. But there's nothing ungrammatical about the sentence without the pronoun. Also, going hiking *at Christmas* does not mean going hiking *at my Christmas*. You're making an assumption that may or may not be true.

Comment: Not sure here, but I think "holidays" means something different in different English speaking countries. In the US, we pretty much all have the same holidays (like Christmas, Thanksgiving, etc.), but isn't it true that in some other countries, whenever you take time off work, or go traveling for fun, it is called a "holiday"? So it might be good to call them "his holidays," to distinguish them from other people's holidays.